# Data mining and weka

Tags: database, weka, data-mining, data-warehouse, decision-tree

Hi ive beeen asked to  search for at least 20 different datasets with a maximum of 40 datasets. i need to apply the following classification techniques using the WEKA software on the chosen datasets:

(1) Decision tree (SimpleCart),

(2) Naïve Bayes, and

(3) K-NN (IBk) (with K taking the value of 1 up to the number of class labels in the dataset)

Once you have applied WEKA on all the datasets, it is required to accomplish the following tasks:

Compare the performance of the applied techniques you have achieved through WEKA. 
Analyse the results with regards to the dataset properties.

Ive never used weka before,am unsure on how to apply the classification techniques and what am actually comparing, but am quick at learning.Am not really about what am required to do...i just need some direction or some example please anyone?

Comment: This is not a programming question. There is a nice book, and Weka has a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

- To find dataset, you can use
  https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html
- To compare the performance of classifier, there are many measures like AUC (Area Under Curve), ROC curve, Accuracy, precision and recall. Weka has the ability to generate these measures. I recommend to use AUC and Accuracy.
- To learn how to use Weka, there are many online tutorials like http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-weka2/